# Simplify jQuery Switch Case

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm using JQVMap, and I have my code to where depending on what state you click, it'll reveal info about that state within a single div below the map. However, I feel there's a simplified, more efficient way to set up this code so there's not a lot of repeat, especially once I start adding more states. Is there?

```
switch(code){
        case"tx":
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-tx)').hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-tx').show("slow");
            break;
        case"il":
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-il)').hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-il').show("slow");
            break;
        case"fl":
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-fl)').hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-fl').show("slow");
            break;
        case"ga":
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-ga)').hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-ga').show("slow");
            break;
        case"pa":
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-pa)').hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-pa').show("slow");
            break;
        default:
            $('#state-name').html(region);
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-uhoh)').hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-uhoh').show("slow");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put it in function instead of writing it all. Create statement dynamically

```
function(code){
            $('#info-children').children(':not(#info-'+ code +')).hide("slow");
            $('#info-children').children('#info-'+ code +').show("slow");
    }
```